# Is it possible for Lightroom to automatically add keywords on import?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, import, automation, keywords

Specifically, I'm looking to automatically add keywords relating to EXIF data, like the camera that the picture was taken with.

The reason I am interested in doing this is because some of the places that I publish to automatically strip the meta-data, but leave the keywords intact. I'd like for the information to remain associated with the image, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Jeffrey Friedl's export plugins allow the opportunity to include EXIF data as metadata in the description / caption / keyword fields with tokens. Specifically I use the free (donationware) [Metadata Wrangler Plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/metadata-wrangler).

In your case you could use the "Special Keyword Processing" section to add keywords using these tokens on export: `{CameraMake} {CameraModel}`

More tokens can be found in the [list of preset templates for Friedl's plugins](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/template).

Answer (score 4):

**Yes to your title question.** No to the one related to EXIF data.

You can specify on import any number of static keywords but, without a third-party plugin, there does not seem to be a way to create keywords dynamically.

What puzzles me is why would you want to add keywords from the EXIF since that would only duplicate information. Lightroom is equally capable of searching and indexing keywords and EXIF information. In the filter bar, for example, if you use 'All Searchable Fields' then LR will match keywords and EXIF for anything you type there.

Comment: thanks Itai, I've updated the question with my reasoning! Perhaps what I'm looking for is adding keywords automatically when photos are Published?

Comment: Yeah. The answer does not changed except that I am no longer puzzled :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing baked in, as @Itai says, but you certainly can extend Lightroom if you don't mind writing a little Lua. Adobe has exposed a great deal of the surface area of Lightroom for people to write plugins. You might start [here on Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom.html) if you are into writing some code.

If you're not the programmer sort or perhaps would rather be a photographer than a coder, perhaps someone has had the exact same problem and solved it for you -- I've not heard of such a plugin, but you can start your search [here at the Adobe Exchange](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=productHome&exc=25).